# What does a zlib header look like?

Tags: header, structure, zlib

In my project I need to know what a `zlib` header looks like. I've heard it's rather simple but I cannot find any description of the zlib header.

For example, does it contain a magic number?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

[Link to RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1950)

```
0   1
+---+---+
|CMF|FLG|
+---+---+
```

CMF (Compression Method and flags)
This byte is divided into a 4-bit compression method and a 4-
bit information field depending on the compression method.

```
bits 0 to 3  CM     Compression method
bits 4 to 7  CINFO  Compression info
```

CM (Compression method)
This identifies the compression method used in the file. `CM = 8`
denotes the "deflate" compression method with a window size up
to 32K. This is the method used by gzip and PNG *and almost everything else.*
CM = 15 is reserved.

CINFO (Compression info)
For CM = 8, CINFO is the base-2 logarithm of the LZ77 window
size, minus eight (CINFO=7 indicates a 32K window size). Values
of CINFO above 7 are not allowed in this version of the
specification.  CINFO is not defined in this specification for
CM not equal to 8.

**In practice, this means the first byte is almost always `78` (hex)**

FLG (FLaGs)
This flag byte is divided as follows:

```
bits 0 to 4  FCHECK  (check bits for CMF and FLG)
bit  5       FDICT   (preset dictionary)
bits 6 to 7  FLEVEL  (compression level)
```

The FCHECK value must be such that CMF and FLG, when viewed as
a 16-bit unsigned integer stored in MSB order (CMF*256 + FLG),
is a multiple of 31.

FLEVEL (Compression level)
These flags are available for use by specific compression
methods.  The "deflate" method (`CM = 8`) sets these flags as
follows:

```
        0 - compressor used fastest algorithm
        1 - compressor used fast algorithm
        2 - compressor used default algorithm
        3 - compressor used maximum compression, slowest algorithm
```

Comment: Alright, so **a lower bit number here refers a less significant bit**, not MSB. I was pretty confused when you said “bit #0.”

Answer (score 147):

zlib magic headers

```
78 01 - No Compression/low
78 5E - Fast Compression
78 9C - Default Compression
78 DA - Best Compression
```

Comment: This helped me figure out what type of compression I was dealing with.  I knew the file was compressed, but was doing searches for some header bytes and this came up.  Thanks!

Comment: When using the Java Inflator (uses ZLIB) I'm seeing header values of 120, -100.  This equates to 78 9C.  Backs up what you said above.

Comment: That is only three of the 64 possible zlib headers. See mwfearnley's answer.

Comment: There are four possible `78` answers - this answer omits `78 5E` - which falls between none/default.  28 other values are less likely to be seen, but still valid.

Answer (score 32):

ZLIB/GZIP headers

```
Level | ZLIB  | GZIP 
  1   | 78 01 | 1F 8B 
  2   | 78 5E | 1F 8B 
  3   | 78 5E | 1F 8B 
  4   | 78 5E | 1F 8B 
  5   | 78 5E | 1F 8B 
  6   | 78 9C | 1F 8B 
  7   | 78 DA | 1F 8B 
  8   | 78 DA | 1F 8B 
  9   | 78 DA | 1F 8B
```

Deflate doesn't have common headers

Comment: The first three bytes of a gzip stream are constant: `1f 8b 08`, for stronger discrimination. Also you are only showing four of the 64 possible zlib headers. See mwfearnley's answer.

Answer (score 30):

The ZLIB header (as defined in [RFC1950](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1950#page-4)) is a 16-bit, big-endian value - in other words, it is two bytes long, with the higher bits in the first byte and the lower bits in the second.

It contains these bitfields from most to least significant:

---

- `CINFO`  (bits 12-15, first byte)
  Indicates the window size as a power of two, from `0` (256 bytes) to `7` (32768 bytes).  This will usually be `7`.  Higher values are not allowed.
- `CM`     (bits 8-11)
  The compression method.  Only Deflate (`8`) is allowed.

---

- `FLEVEL` (bits 6-7, second byte)
  Roughly indicates the compression level, from `0` (fast/low) to `3` (slow/high)
- `FDICT`  (bit 5)
  Indicates whether a preset dictionary is used.  This is usually `0`.
  (`1` is technically allowed, but I don't know of any Deflate formats that define preset dictionaries.)
- `FCHECK` (bits 0-4)
  A checksum (5 bits, `0`..`31`), whose value is calculated such that the entire value divides 31 with no remainder.<sup>*</sup>

---

Typically, only the `CINFO` and `FLEVEL` fields can be freely changed, and `FCHECK` must be calculated based on the final value.  Assuming no preset dictionary, there is no choice in what the other fields contain, so a total of 32 possible headers are valid.  Here they are:

```
      FLEVEL: 0       1       2       3
CINFO:
     0      08 1D   08 5B   08 99   08 D7
     1      18 19   18 57   18 95   18 D3
     2      28 15   28 53   28 91   28 CF
     3      38 11   38 4F   38 8D   38 CB
     4      48 0D   48 4B   48 89   48 C7
     5      58 09   58 47   58 85   58 C3
     6      68 05   68 43   68 81   68 DE
     7      78 01   78 5E   78 9C   78 DA
```

The `CINFO` field is rarely, if ever, set by compressors to be anything other than `7` (indicating the maximum 32KB window), so the only values you are likely to see in the wild are the four in the bottom row (beginning with `78`).

<sup>* (You might wonder if there's a small amount of leeway on the value of `FCHECK` - could it be set to either of 0 or 31 if both pass the checksum?  In practice though, this can only occur if `FDICT=1`, so it doesn't feature in the above table.)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the exhaustive information. This should be the accepted answer to this question.

Comment: Bonus fact: when FLEVEL is 1 and CINFO is at least 2, both bytes are ASCII-printable, so `(S`, `8O`, `HK`, `XG`, `hC`, `x^` are valid headers.  PNGOUT uses `x^` (`78 5E`) when compressing images.

Answer (score 20):

Following is the Zlib compressed data format.

```
 +---+---+
 |CMF|FLG| (2 bytes - Defines the compression mode - More details below)
 +---+---+
 +---+---+---+---+
 |     DICTID    | (4 bytes. Present only when FLG.FDICT is set.) - Mostly not set
 +---+---+---+---+
 +=====================+
 |...compressed data...| (variable size of data)
 +=====================+
 +---+---+---+---+
 |     ADLER32   |  (4 bytes of checksum)
 +---+---+---+---+
```

Mostly, `FLG.FDICT` (Dictionary flag) is not set. In such cases the `DICTID` is simply not present. So, the total hear is just 2 bytes.

The header values(`CMF` and `FLG`) with no dictionary are defined as follows.

```
 CMF |  FLG
0x78 | 0x01 - No Compression/low
0x78 | 0x9C - Default Compression
0x78 | 0xDA - Best Compression
```

More at [ZLIB RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1950)

Comment: This summary shows only three of the 64 possible zlib headers. See mwfearnley's answer.

Answer (score 5):

All answers here are most probably correct, however - if you want to manipulate ZLib compression stream directly, and it was produced by using `gz_open, gzwrite, gzclose` functions - then there is extra 10 leading bytes header before zlib compression steam comes - and those are produced by function gz_open - header looks like this:

```
    fprintf(s->file, "%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c", gz_magic[0], gz_magic[1],
         Z_DEFLATED, 0 /*flags*/, 0,0,0,0 /*time*/, 0 /*xflags*/, OS_CODE);
```

And results in following hex dump: `1F 8B 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 0B`
followed by zlib compression stream.

But there is also trailing 8 bytes - they are `uLong` - crc over whole file, `uLong` - uncompressed file size - look for following bytes at end of stream:

```
    putLong (s->file, s->crc);
    putLong (s->file, (uLong)(s->in & 0xffffffff));
```

Comment: Everything is explained here : https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1952

Comment: Those are gzip streams, not zlib streams. Two different things.