# How to decompress data from a memory stream in C#

Tags: c#, memorystream, compression, deflate

I am trying to decompress a compressed base64 encoded string but have no idea how to do so. It is not a gzip and I am trying to decompress it without having to write to a file.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17212964/net-zlib-inflate-with-net-4-5

Comment: Step 1: understand how the data was compressed

Comment: Please provide the base64 encoding of the data here, or at least the first hundred characters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unzip a memorystream (Contains the zip file) and get the files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12715945/unzip-a-memorystream-contains-the-zip-file-and-get-the-files)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried suggestions from [Unzip a memorystream (Contains the zip file) and get the files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12715945/unzip-a-memorystream-contains-the-zip-file-and-get-the-files) and finally found one that works with some changes made to use it as a method.

```
public static string DecompressData(string val)
    {
        byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(val).ToArray();
        Stream data = new MemoryStream(bytes);
        Stream unzippedEntryStream;  
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(data);
        foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries)
        {
            unzippedEntryStream = entry.Open();
            unzippedEntryStream.CopyTo(ms);  
        }

        string result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
        return result;
    }
```