# Building a fast PNG encoder issues

Tags: compression, png, zlib, libpng, encoder

I am trying to build a fast 8-bit greyscale PNG encoder. Unfortunately I must be misunderstanding part of the spec. Smaller image sizes seem to work, but the larger ones will only open in some image viewers. This image (with multiple DEFLATE Blocks) gives a
"Decompression error in IDAT" error in my image viewer but opens fine in my browser:
[image: sample grayscale image]

This image has just one DEFLATE block but also gives an error:

[image: smaller sample grayscale image]

Below I will outline what I put in my IDAT chunk in case you can easily spot any mistakes (note, images and steps have been modified based on answers, but there is still a problem):

1. IDAT length
2. "IDAT" in ascii (literally the bytes 0x49 0x44 0x41 0x54)
3. Zlib header 0x78 0x01

Steps 4-7 are for every deflate block, as the data may need to be broken up:

4. The byte 0x00 or 0x01, depending on if it is a middle or the last block.
5. Number of bytes in block (up to 2^16-1) stored as a little endian 16-bit integer
6. The 1's complement of this integer representation.
7. Image data (each scan-line is starts with a zero-byte for the no filter option in PNG, and is followed by width bytes of greyscale pixel data)
8. An adler-32 checksum of  all the image data
9. A CRC of all the IDAT data

I've tried `pngcheck` on linux, an it does not spot any errors. If nobody can see what is wrong, can you point me in the right direction for a debugging tool?

My last resort is to use the libpng library to make my own decoder, and debug from there.

Some people have suggested it may be my adler-32 function calculation:

```
static uint32_t adler32(uint32_t height, uint32_t width, char** pixel_array)
{
  uint32_t a=1,b=0,w,h;
  for(h=0;h<height;h++)
    {
      b+=a;
      for(w=0;w<width;w++)
        {
          a+=pixel_array[h][w];
          b+=a;
        }
    }
  return (uint32_t)(((b%65521)*65536)|(a%65521));
}
```

Note that because the pixel_array passed to the function does not contain the zero-byte at the beginning of each scanline (needed for PNG) there is an extra b+=a (and implicit a+=0) at the beginning of each iteration of the outer loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 4. The byte 0x00 or 0x80, depending on if it is a middle or the last block.

Change the `0x80` to `0x01` and all will be well.

The `0x80` is appearing as a stored block that is *not* the last block.  All that's being looked at is the low bit, which is zero, indicating a middle block.  All of the data is in that "middle" block, so a decoder will recover the full image.  Some liberal PNG decoders may then ignore the errors it gets when it tries to decode the next block, which isn't there, and then ignore the missing check values (Adler-32 and CRC-32), etc.  That's why it shows up ok in browsers, even though it is an invalid PNG file.

There are two things wrong with your Adler-32 code.  First, you are accessing the data from a `char` array.  `char` is signed, so your `0xff` bytes are being added *not* as 255, but rather as -127.  You need to make the array `unsigned char` or cast it to that before extracting byte values from it.

Second, you are doing the modulo operation too late.  You must do the `% 65521` before the `uint32_t` overflows.  Otherwise you don't get the modulo of the sum as required by the algorithm.  A simple fix would be to do the `% 65521` to `a` and `b` right after the width loop, inside the height loop.  This will work so long as you can guarantee that the width will be less than 5551 bytes.  (Why 5551 is left as an exercise for the reader.)  If you cannot guarantee that, then you will need to embed a another loop to consume bytes from the line until you get to 5551 of them, do the modulo, and then continue with the line.  Or, a smidge slower, just run a counter and do the modulo when it gets to the limit.

Here is an example of a version that works for any width:

```
static uint32_t adler32(uint32_t height, uint32_t width, unsigned char ** pixel_array)
{
    uint32_t a = 1, b = 0, w, h, k;
    for (h = 0; h < height; h++)
    {
        b += a;
        w = k = 0;
        while (k < width) {
            k += 5551;
            if (k > width)
                k = width;
            while (w < k) {
                a += pixel_array[h][w++];
                b += a;
            }
            a %= 65521;
            b %= 65521;
        }
    }
    return (b << 16) | a;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I now use '0x01' at the beginning of the last block, but an issue still persists. I've updated the original post with another, more simple example, and the correct spelling of your name :)

Comment: I've verified this is the issue, so I now know where to start debugging. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I *do* get an error with `pngcheck`: "zlib: inflate error = -3 (data error)". As your PNG scaffolding structure looks okay, it's time to take a low-level look into the `IDAT` block with a hex viewer. (I'm going to type this up while working through it.)

The header looks alright; `IDAT` length is okay. Your zlib flags are `78 01` ("No/low compression", see also [What does a zlib header look like?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9050260/what-does-a-zlib-header-look-like)), where one of my own tools use `78 9C` ("Default compression"), but then again, these flags are only informative.

Next: zlib's internal blocks (per [RFC1950](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1950)).

Directly after the compression flags (`CMF` in RFC1950) it expects FLATE compressed data, which is the only compression scheme zlib supports. And that is in another <s>castle</s> RFC: [RFC1951](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1951).

Each separately compression *block* is prepended by a byte:

> 3.2.3. Details of block format
>
> Each block of compressed data begins with 3 header bits
> containing the following data:

```
        first bit       BFINAL
        next 2 bits     BTYPE
```

> ...
> BFINAL is set if and only if this is the last block of the data
> set.

BTYPE specifies how the data are compressed, as follows:

> 

```
        00 - no compression
        01 - compressed with fixed Huffman codes
        10 - compressed with dynamic Huffman codes
        11 - reserved (error)
```

So this value can be set to `00` for 'not last block, uncompressed' and to `01` for 'last block, uncompressed', immediately followed by the length (2 bytes) and its bitwise inverse, per **3.2.4. Non-compressed blocks (BTYPE=00)**:

> 3.2.4. Non-compressed blocks (BTYPE=00)
>
> Any bits of input up to the next byte boundary are ignored.
> The rest of the block consists of the following information:

```
          0   1   2   3   4...
        +---+---+---+---+================================+
        |  LEN  | NLEN  |... LEN bytes of literal data...|
        +---+---+---+---+================================+
```

> LEN is the number of data bytes in the block.  NLEN is the
> one's complement of LEN.

They are the final 4 bytes in your `IDAT` segment. Why do small images work, and larger not? Because you only have *2 bytes* for the length.<sup>1</sup> You need to break up your image into blocks no larger than 65,535 bytes (in my own PNG creator I seem to have used 32,768, probably "for safety"). If the last block, write out `01`, else `00`. Then add the two times two `LEN` bytes, properly encoded, followed by exactly `LEN` data bytes. Repeat until done.

The Adler-32 checksum is *not* part of this Flate-compressed data, and should not be counted in the blocks of `LEN` data. (It is still part of the `IDAT` block, though.)

---

After re-reading your question to verify I addressed all of your issues (and confirming I spelled "Adler-32" correctly), I realized you describe all of the *steps* right -- <s>except that the 'last block' indicator is `01`, not `80`</s> (later edit: uh, perhaps you *are* right about that!) -- but that it **does not show** in this sample PNG. See if you can get it to work following all of the steps *by the letter*.

<sup>**Kudos for doing this 'by hand'.** It's a nice exercise in 'following the specs', and if you get this to work, it may be worthwhile to try and add proper compression. I shun pre-made libraries as much as possible; the only allowance I made for my own PNG encoder/decoder was to use Rich Geldreich's [`miniz.c`](http://code.google.com/p/miniz/), because implementing proper Flate encoding/decoding is beyond my ken.</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> That's not the whole story. Browsers are particularly forgiving in HTML errors; it seems they are as forgiving for PNG errors as well. Safari displays your image just fine, and so does Preview. But they may just all be sharing OS X's PNG decoder, because Photoshop *rejects* the file.

Comment: Thank you for the help.From what I have read of your response, I have followed those rules. My data is broken up into blocks of max length of 2^16-1. However, for last block uncompressed I use 0x08 instead of 0x01. Shouldn't the first bit be set to a one, instead of the fifth?

Comment: But the block indicator and next block length (and its inverse) do not show up in your file! As I understand, they should appear at least once, immediately after the `78 01` zlib flags; and then every next 65,535 bytes, or shorter.

Comment: Again, than you for the help. I really appreciate it.
I believe the block indicator and length do appear right after 78 01, unless I uploaded the file incorrectly: 78 01 00 FF FF 00 00. The first "00" is the block indicator, "FF FF" is the first block length (completely full) and the "00 00" is the 1's compliment.
I'm not sure that was the issue. Any more insight you could provide is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Okay, it's late (local time) but I'll go over the hex dump again and make sure I am counting right. It certainly sounds as if you are doing everything correct. In the mean time .. I can't recall whether or not I originally tested the `01` vs `80` "last block" indicator issue thorougly, so you may as well try the other one.

Comment: Thanks. Also, in my first comment I'm sure you noticed some typos. It should read "I use 0x80 instead of 0x01. Shouldn't the first bit be set to one instead of the last?"

Here is another image that was generated (all gray to assist with debugging) that may help. https://mega.co.nz/#!m4EHyY7T!Abqhl47Lxvbz-m_SOHs8vZrmFgqI0MUrCI8sWXuVzlQ