# iOS compression_encode_buffer doesn't include zlib header?

Tags: ios, swift, zlib

I'm using `compression_encode_buffer` with `COMPRESSION_ZLIB` to zlib-compress data in an iOS app, but the result is missing the zlib header.

For example:

```
size = compression_encode_buffer(
    destinationBuffer, destinationBufferSize,
    sourceBuffer, sourceBufferSize, nil,
    COMPRESSION_ZLIB
)
```

Will return the bytes:

```
AD 53 C1 8E 9B 30 …
```

While using, for example, Python's `data.encode("zlib")` on the same data will return:

```
78 9C AD 53 C1 8E 9B 30 …
^^ ^^ correct zlib header
```

What's up with that? Why isn't the header being included? And is there a "correct" way to add it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The two bytes are a zlib header, not a magic number.  Most likely you are missing the final 4 bytes of the stream (the ADLER32 checksum) as well, and only have the "deflate" datastream that you expected to be wrapped in a zlib datatstream.  The [iOS documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/Compression/index.html) says as much:

```
ZLIB
The encoded format is the raw DEFLATE format as described
in IETF RFC 1951 Using the ZLIB library
```

They should have called the compression method "DEFLATE" not "ZLIB".

See this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35215082/how-to-fix-a-zlib-file-without-headerhttp://) about dealing with ZLIB vs DEFLATE data.

Comment: That's funny. They made the exact opposite mistake that the HTTP authors made when they called zlib-wrapped streams "deflate".

Comment: Is there a way to get a "headerful/checksum" zlib thing out of iOS then? Without resorting to 3rd party imports?