# Deflate with Pako and inflate with asp net core

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, zlib, pako

I'm trying to deflate a .xlsx file on the front end and inflate it in the server side, in a asp net core 2.2 server.

I tried everything and i have this now:

```
//JS code
handleSaveFile = (file) => {
    var compressedFile = pako.deflate(JSON.stringify(file), { to: 'string' });
    this.setState({ file: compressedFile });
  }
```

Completely straight forward, pako.deflate is enough to do the trick.

Now on the back-end i tried everything but according to the documentation ends up like this:
[image]

I tried also GZipStream, but the result is the same. I cant find anything regarding compress/decompress but there is plenty of info regarding the other way around.

Comment: What's the documentation you referred to? It would be better if you share the complete view code that can reproduce the issue(include  how to call the server-side method from js).

Comment: There not much to say, the pako compression is one line of code. Works just fine in the server because i already have it working without compression. What i'm now doing is trying to deflate the body in the server, until now without success.

Comment: Is there any update? I also stuck in this problem

Comment: kinda ignored the situation because my use case doesn't require a file bigger than 25 mb, but eventually will come about. But for sure is not an easy task

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look this, hope will help:

Client:

```
let output = pako.gzip(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Server:

```
public static string Decompress(byte[] data)
{
    // Read the last 4 bytes to get the length
    byte[] lengthBuffer = new byte[4];
    Array.Copy(data, data.Length - 4, lengthBuffer, 0, 4);
    int uncompressedSize = BitConverter.ToInt32(lengthBuffer, 0);

    var buffer = new byte[uncompressedSize];
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream(data))
    {
        using (var gzip = new GZipStream(ms, CompressionMode.Decompress))
        {
            gzip.Read(buffer, 0, uncompressedSize);
        }
    }
    string json = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer); 
    return json;
}
```

detail in :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66825721/1979406