# Python - String changing after decoding and encoding again (zlib + base64)

Tags: python, base64, zlib

I have this very simple Python code:

```
in_data = "eNrtmD1Lw0AY..."
print("Input: " + in_data)
out_data = in_data.decode('base64').decode('zlib').encode('zlib').encode('base64')
print("Output: " + out_data)
```

It outputs:

```
Input: eNrtmD1Lw0AY...
Output: eJztmE1LAkEY...
```

The string is also correctly decoded; if I display `in_data.decode('base64').decode('zlib')`, it gives the expected result.

Also, the formatting is different for both strings:

[image: Weird formatting]

Why is the decoding/encoding not working properly? Are there some sort of parameters I should use?

Comment: The formatting follows standard base64 rules; newlines are permitted and preferred at 76 columns. Perhaps your input data used a heavier or lighter compression setting?

Comment: Please include the *full input string* so we can properly diagnose.

Comment: Here it is: http://pastebin.com/LUy2Ybs4

Comment: Seeing as the `N` and `J` are what differs first, I'd say this is a [different compression setting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9050260/what-does-a-zlib-header-look-like). You have 78DA on the input, 789C on your output. That's a different, lower compression ratio (default).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data on input starts with the hex bytes `78 DA`, your output starts with `78 9C`:

```
>>> 'eNrt'.decode('base64').encode('hex')[:4]
'78da'
>>> 'eJzt'.decode('base64').encode('hex')[:4]
'789c'
```

`DA` is the highest compression level, `9C` is the default. See [What does a zlib header look like?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9050260/what-does-a-zlib-header-look-like)

Rather than use `.encode('zlib')` use the [`zlib.compress()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zlib.html#zlib.compress), an set the level to 9:

```
import zlib

zlib.compress(decoded_data, 9).encode('base64')
```

The output of the base64 encoding inserts a newline every 76 characters to make it suitable for MIME encapsulation (emailing). You could use the [`base64.b64encode()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/base64.html#base64.b64encode) instead to encode without newlines.