# php compression filters and gzcompress not returning the same result

Tags: php, compression, zlib

I get different output when I run my code through zlib [compression filters](http://php.net/manual/en/filters.compression.php)

My code:

```
<?php
$data = 'zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz';

$params = array('level' => 6, 'window' => 15, 'memory' => 9);
//$params = 6;
$fp = fopen('php://memory', 'wb+');
stream_filter_append($fp, 'zlib.deflate', STREAM_FILTER_WRITE, $params);
fputs($fp, $data);
rewind($fp);

echo bin2hex(stream_get_contents($fp)) . "\n";
echo bin2hex(gzcompress($data)) . "\n";
```

The output:

```
789c
789cabaaa2260000bce3252d
```

It's my understanding that 789c is the [header for normal compression](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30794147/569976). So I have no idea what's up. Do compression streams just not work in PHP?

Any ideas would be appreciated - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your string is much too short to fill the DEFLATE working buffer. And because your stream is not explicitly closed, it doesn't get processed at all, nor flushed. Your data is still pending in the buffer when stream_get_contents() is called.

If we force a buffer flush by injecting a large enough block of random bytes, some data gets actually written to the stream:

```
$data = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(65536);

$params = array('level' => 6, 'window' => 15, 'memory' => 9);
$fp = fopen('php://memory', 'wb+');
stream_filter_append($fp, 'zlib.deflate', STREAM_FILTER_WRITE, $params);
fputs($fp, $data);
rewind($fp);

echo substr(bin2hex(stream_get_contents($fp)), 0, 32) . "\n";
echo substr(bin2hex(gzcompress($data)), 0, 32) . "\n";
```

Example output (just displaying the 16 first bytes):

```
789c000b80f47f453c070e41c557acdb
789c000b80f47f453c070e41c557acdb
```

On the other hand, the ZLIB header (78 9C = default compression) can be safely written from the beginning because its content doesn't depend on the next coming bytes. There's no need for a buffer in that case.

Comment: I don't suppose it's possible to perform partial flushes? For compression with SSH you need to. Quoting https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4253#section-6.2 , "*The compression context is initialized after each key exchange, and is passed from one packet to the next, with only a partial flush being performed at the end of each packet. A partial flush means that the current compressed block is ended and all data will be output.*"

Comment: @neubert I don't think you can have a total control on the partial flushes with these functions. You should get more frequent flushes by setting `'memory' => 1`, but I'm not sure it's a viable solution.

Comment: This answer looks correct but it isn't because the whole result of `stream_get_contents()` is still incomplete. You may force the filter to complete the compression by removing it through `stream_filter_remove()`. At least [this](https://3v4l.org/K1f3G) works. Or did I missed something else?

Comment: @JanSlabon That looks indeed like a cleaner way of forcing the compression to complete.

Comment: @Arnauld did I missed the dirty one? Is there another way?

Comment: @JanSlabon The other way is mine (injecting enough random data). It also forces the compressed data to be flushed, but your method looks better.