# Data format for System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream

Tags: .net, c, powershell, zlib

I need to be able to compress a data stream with PowerShell and decompress it with my C program using zlib.

I'm using `System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream` in PowerShell to compress, but the decompression with zlib in my C program does not work.

Apparently `DeflateStream` adds extra data/header to the output. If that's right, I want to know its format so I can implement a decompression with zlib.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer my own question, it's actually the opposite.

`System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream` doesn't add any extra data, it outputs a raw deflate stream with no header/metadata.

I actually had to add the ZLib header to the stream. See [RFC 1950](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1950).

This answer also helped me:

[What does a zlib header look like?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9050260/what-does-a-zlib-header-look-like)

In detail, there must be two bytes in a zlib header:

```
0   1
+---+---+
|CMF|FLG|
+---+---+
```

#### First byte (CMF):

Each nibble (half-byte) of the first byte has a meaning:

```
bits 0 to 3  CM     Compression method
bits 4 to 7  CINFO  Compression info
```

You can see it in more detail in the answer I've mentioned above.

#### Second byte (FLG):

FLG (FLaGs) This flag byte is divided as follows:

```
bits 0 to 4  FCHECK  (check bits for CMF and FLG)
bit  5       FDICT   (preset dictionary)
bits 6 to 7  FLEVEL  (compression level)
```

The most common headers are:

```
78 01 - No Compression/low
78 9C - Default Compression
78 DA - Best Compression
```

I've added the header `78 9C` before `System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream`'s output, but there's one more step as @Mark Adler said in the comments: we have to add an Adler-32 checksum at the end of the stream.

## Edit:

In the end, I was trying to reinvent the wheel. I can use `System.IO.Compression.GZipStream` in the PowerShell compression and just use `inflateInit2()` in the decompression and all should be ok (thanks to @Mark Adler's suggestion).

Comment: It can't "work like a charm" if you don't also add the check value at the end. `inflate()` will not return with `Z_STREAM_END` without that, which is what indicates success. You will have no idea whether your stream was incomplete or not if you just accept `Z_OK`. You don't need to add the the zlib header anyway. You can use `inflateInit2()` to request a raw inflate, in which case it will return `Z_STREAM_END` if complete. Also I would recommend that you use `GZipStream` instead to provide a proper wrapper with integrity checking. You can use `inflateInit2()` to request gzip decoding.