# TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' when using zlib compress methods in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I ran the following code :

```
import zlib
import sys
s = 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'
t = sys.getsizeof(zlib.compress(s))
print(t)
print(sys.getsizeof(zlib.decompress(t)))
```

I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [zlib TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51348407/zlib-typeerror-a-bytes-like-object-is-required-not-str)

Answer (score -1):

You can compress `s`, if is of type `bytes`:

`s = b'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'`

This then returns `44` for `t`. But I don't know, why you want to decompress an integer?

Maybe the example should read like this:

```
import zlib
import sys
s = b'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'
c = zlib.compress(s)
d = zlib.decompress(c)
print(s, sys.getsizeof(s))
print(c, sys.getsizeof(c))
print(d, sys.getsizeof(d))
```

which gives

```
b'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa' 59
b'x\x9cKL\xc4\x05\x00\x85\x19\t\xdb' 44
b'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa' 59
```