# How to decompress a hex string using zlib?

Tags: python, compression, zlib, python-3.8

I have a data packet that gets compressed on one end using zlib.

I need to decompress the data packet on the other end, using Python (I'm using zlib as well).

It seems to me that it should be pretty straightforward, however, I am not having any success.

This is basically what my data looks like:

```
# Compressed hex string (formatted by me with a space in between bytes):
compressed_hexstr = "10 84 35 4F 3E A3 CE E1"
```

EDIT - I am basically getting the compressed data packet as a string. I then run a parsing program to extract info from the compressed data packet that I need in order to tell it how to continue to parse. To get that info, I need to split the data packet string into bytes (which I do with a simple function that just grabs the first two characters and puts them together, appending them to an empty list, and then continuing to the next 2, and appending again until the end). Later, I end up joining the list with a space in between.

```
decompressed = zlib.decompress(compressed_hexstr)
print(f"decompressed: {decompressed}")
```

Returns

> TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

I've also made the hex string into bytes (with `bytes.fromhex()`) and into a bytearray (with `bytearray.fromhex()`).

I get the following errors:

```
Using bytes.fromhex(compressed_hexstr):
>> zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check

Using bytes.fromhex(compressed_hexstr, -15):  **NOTE: I don't quite understand the wbits argument**
>> zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing data: invalid stored block lengths

Using bytearray.fromhex(compressed_hexstr):
>> zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check

Using bytearray.fromhex(compressed_hexstr, -15):
>> zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing data: invalid stored block lengths
```

[zlib TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51348407/zlib-typeerror-a-bytes-like-object-is-required-not-str) seems to be the closest thing I have found to my problem (because of all the similar errors) but I still can't seem to get this to work.

Comment: How are you formatting the data so it has a space in between bytes? Please add code that does that to your question if it's very long (i.e. don't try to put it down here is a comment).

Comment: @martineau I am basically getting the compressed data packet as a string. I then run a parsing program to extract info from the compressed data packet that I need in order to tell it how to continue to parse. To get that info, I need to split the data packet string into bytes (which I do with a simple function that just grabs the first two characters and puts them together, appending them to an empty list, and then continuing to the next 2, and appending again until the end). Later, I end up joining the list with a space in between.

Answer (score 1):

`10 84 35 4F 3E A3 CE E1`, when converted to bytes, *is not zlib data*. It does not start with a zlib header, and it is invalid if interpreted as a raw deflate stream.

I recommend you look at the data immediately after it is compressed on the other end, and compare that to what you are receiving.