C# ZLibStream does not recode to same value
I have a data value from a webpage URL which undergoes some coding to get the parameters argument.
One part of the code it a ZLib compression, and here is the problem:
I use .NET 8.0 and System.IO.Compression.ZLibStream to do the compression and decompression.
When I use the value, decompress it and then recompress it, I get not the same data as before. The problem is also that when I use a new argument to be compressed, the processing webpage does not get the argument (the webpage uses pako.deflate und pako.inflate. I tries several things but now I do not know how to go on.
This is the code which I wrote for test:
`'''<summary>Reproduction of the ZLIB problem.</summary>
Public Sub ZLibProblem()

    'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62755194/c-sharp-equivalent-to-zlib-decompress
    'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62755194/c-sharp-equivalent-to-zlib-decompress

    'Problematic input from the website -> code as bytes
     Dim InputString As String = "78 9C BB F9 A8 24 B5 A2 C4 56 D5 DC 49 D5 C8 A8 2C 31 A7 34 15 48 AB 1A 3B 82 48 20 32 77 51 4B CB CC 29 49 2D 8A 2F A9 2C 48 2D C6 A2 CE 14 24 E0 13 0 E2 99 BA A8 1A 39 3 19 B9 89 25 C9 19 21 40 F5 10 25 79 A5 39 39 20 83 52 12 4B 12 E3 8B F3 4B 8B 92 53 6D 43 82 1C C3 5C 7D 7C 5C 83 D4 12 93 B 4B 33 8B 33 4B 32 F3 F3 E2 73 F3 F3 4A 32 70 5A E2 EB 18 44 84 2D 5 89 E9 A9 B6 86 60 2A 38 B3 A C8 34 30 0 0 F8 3C 44 D0"
     Dim Compressed As Byte() = HexStringToBytes(InputString)

     'Uncompress and re-compress
     Dim Uncompressed As Byte() = ZLibUncompress(Compressed)
     Dim ReGen() As Byte = ZLibCompress(Uncompressed)
     Dim ErrorPositions As List(Of Integer) = GetDiffs(Compressed, ReGen)

     'Uncompress and re-compress
     Dim Uncompressed2 As Byte() = ZLibUncompress(ReGen)
     Dim ReGen2() As Byte = ZLibCompress(Uncompressed2)
     Dim ErrorPositions2 As List(Of Integer) = GetDiffs(Compressed, ReGen2)

     Dim UncompressedDiff As List(Of Integer) = GetDiffs(Uncompressed, Uncompressed2)
     Dim ReGenDiff As List(Of Integer) = GetDiffs(ReGen, ReGen2)

    'ErrorPositions show 5 errors, ReGen and ReGen2 are identical as Uncompressed and Uncompressed2 are

End Sub

'──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
' Original library with .NET ZLibStream
'──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

'''<summary>Uncompress the bytes using ZLib.</summary>
Private Function ZLibUncompress(ByVal Bytes As Byte()) As Byte()
    Dim RetVal(10000) As Byte
    Dim ContentLength As Integer = -1
    Using ms As New IO.MemoryStream(Bytes)
        Using ZLib As New System.IO.Compression.ZLibStream(ms, System.IO.Compression.CompressionMode.Decompress)
            ContentLength = ZLib.Read(RetVal, 0, RetVal.Count)
        End Using
    End Using
    ReDim Preserve RetVal(ContentLength - 1)
    Return RetVal
End Function

'''<summary>Compress the bytes using ZLib.</summary>
Private Function ZLibCompress(ByVal Bytes As Byte()) As Byte()
    Dim ContentLength As Integer = -1
    Dim RetVal() As Byte
    Using ms As New IO.MemoryStream()
        Using ZLib As New System.IO.Compression.ZLibStream(ms, IO.Compression.CompressionMode.Compress)
            ZLib.Write(Bytes, 0, Bytes.Count)
            ZLib.Flush()
            ContentLength = CInt(ms.Position)
        End Using
        RetVal = ms.ToArray
    End Using
    ReDim Preserve RetVal(ContentLength - 1)
    Return RetVal
End Function

I tried several things, added a lot of debug stuff, but I never get the same output as I put in the chain decompression - compression.
I also tried the routine by random data input, compress, then decompress and compress again, always with identical results. It seems that there is something special on this sequence ...
UPDATE: I replaced ZLibStream with the SharpCompress library - and now it works. There seem to be a speciality with the byte sequence in combination with the .NET ZLib functionality. For me it works now, but still a little bit confusing ...

This seems normal. It is 100% required that if you take a raw value, compress it and decompress it, that you get back the same raw value. However, if you take a compressed value; decompress it and recompress it, it is not required to have the same compressed representation. Most compression formats have a wide range of possible compressed values that represent the same raw bytes, depending on parameters and arbitrary implementation choices. If a design is based on being able to reproduce the same compressed value: that's a questionable design.
